# How to work through this regex problem in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, verilog

I am trying to generate a python script, which should read a verilog code line by line and when it encounters 'input some_name;' it should match the line and return name so that I can count what all input ports I have defined in my verilog code (verilog code is very big).
so the verilog code goes like this

```
module(a,b,c,d, vbg
`ifdef USE_GOOD_PIN     
, vb, vc, vd, vg ..... some more input and outputs
`endif
 );

input  [7:0] t_d;
input srd;
output comb;
output src;
inout  [1:0] Iout;
output a_in;
output b_in;
input ff_parity;
```

the code I am trying to match with ('input [7:0] t_d;''input srd;' etc) is

```
 import re
 file = open(r'D:/pyfile/verilog.v' ,"r")
 lines = file.readlines()
 print(len(lines))
 for i in range(0,len(lines)):
      print(lines[i],end = '')
      match = re.match(r'input (.*)',lines[i], re.M|re.I)
      if (match):
            print(match.group(1))
      else:
            print("nomatch")
```

again there can be a single or multiple spaces between 'input' and '[]' and 'name' so how to exactly get the name like 't_d' or 'srd' using python regexes.

with the code I have put I am unable to match the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can match variable whitespace with `\s*` (zero or more spaces) or `\s+` (one or more spaces), and you can 'capture' text with `(...)` parentheses.

Looking at [this description of the Verilog `input` syntax](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/syntax2.html), you can see that you would look for `input` followed by an optional range, followed by 1 or more identifiers, which are [delimited by whitespace](http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00018.htm). The following pattern would capture the *list* of identifiers from such a statement:

```
r'^input\s+(?:\[[^\]]*\]\s+)?(.+);'
```

The `(?:\[[^\]]*\]\s+)?` part would match the optional range syntax (a `[`, followed by any number on non-`]` characters, followed by `]`), without capturing it. See https://regex101.com/r/cT0Q0X/1 for an online demo.

Because the identifiers are always whitespace delimited, you can then use `str.split()` to turn that captured value into a Python list.

You don't need to read the file into memory or use `range`. Just loop over the file directly. And you don't need to use `re.M`, as you are processing individual lines. I'd also drop `re.I`, as Verilog is case sensitive; `INPUT` is not the same thing as `input`:

```
with open(r'D:/pyfile/verilog.v') as file:
    for line in file:
        match = re.search(r'^input\s+(?:\[[^\]]*\]\s+)?(.+);', line)
        if match:
            identifiers = match.group(1).split()
            print(*identifiers)
```

Demo using your sample:

```
>>> import re
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> sample = '''\
... module(a,b,c,d, vbg
... `ifdef USE_GOOD_PIN
... , vb, vc, vd, vg ..... some more input and outputs
... `endif
...  );
...
... input  [7:0] t_d;
... input srd;
... output comb;
... output src;
... inout  [1:0] Iout;
... output a_in;
... output b_in;
... input ff_parity;
... '''
>>> with StringIO(sample) as file:
...     for line in file:
...         match = re.search(r'^input\s+(?:\[[^\]]*\]\s+)?(.+);', line)
...         if match:
...             identifiers = match.group(1).split()
...             print(*identifiers)
...
t_d
srd
ff_parity
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code changes should do the trick.

```
match = re.match(r'input\s+(.*)\s*(.*)',lines[i], re.M|re.I)
if (match):
    matches = list(match.groups())
    if '' in matches:
        matches.remove('')
    print matches[-1]
else:
    print 'nomatch'
```

The '\s' character sequence matches white space. [This](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) is a good tutorial for regular expressions.

Comment: You have simply turned the whole input string into a list of characters. And since that always will lack an empty character, this throws `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have fixed the valuerror part. Thanks.

Comment: You still are printing the wrong output. Why the `list(match.group())`? `match.group()` is **not the captured part**.

Comment: Also, you *always* capture two groups, both with `.*`. For multiple identifiers on a `input` line, this will absolutely give you the wrong values. For long lines, the backtracking cost is going to be significant as well.

Comment: Meant to use match.groups() instead of match.group(). Thanks. Agreed my solution won't work for all possibilities of verilog syntax.